# ¿Cuándo es aceptable omitir "ser" en frases pasivas?

Tags: gramática

En esta cita de *Cien años de soledad*, la cláusula dependiente ha omitido la forma conjugada de *ser* e hipotetizo que tiene que ver con *ser* dirigiendo la oración principal. ¿Qué piensan?

> Era en realidad una selección de clase, **sólo que determinada** por
>   sentimientos de amistad, pues los favorecidos no sólo eran los más
>   antiguos allegados a la casa de José Arcadio Buendía desde antes de
>   emprender el éxodo que culminó con la fundación de Macondo, sino que
>   sus hijos y nietos eran los compañeros habituales de Aureliano y
>   Arcadio desde la infancia, y sus hijas eran las únicas que visitaban
>   la casa para bordar con Rebeca y Amaranta.

Y la traducción:

> It was truly a high-class list, except that **it was determined** by
>   feelings of friendship, for those favored were not only the oldest
>   friends of José Arcadio Buendía’s house since before they undertook
>   the exodus and the founding of Macondo, but also their sons and
>   grandsons, who were the constant companions of Aureliano and Arcadio
>   since infancy, and their daughters, who were the only ones who visited
>   the house to embroider with Rebeca and Amaranta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La frase en negrita no representa una oración pasiva en la versión en español. Si te fijas ahí "determinada" hace de adjetivo que modifica a "selección", solo que omitido por no repetirlo. Una redacción más sencilla de la frase podría ser:

> Era en realidad una selección de clase determinada por sentimientos de amistad...

Quizá la traducción al inglés podría haber sido así:

> It was truly a high-class list, determined by feelings of friendship...

La estructura de la frase es:

> [Aquello (sujeto omitido)] era [una selección de clase determinada por... (predicado)].

Se podría pensar en convertir la frase a pasiva así:

> Aquella selección de clase era determinada por los sentimientos de amistad...

En contraposición a:

> Los sentimientos de amistad... determinaban aquella selección de clase.

Comment: oops....Quise sugerir una edición, no editarla. Tengo demasiado poder. Examina mi sugerencia, pero ahora entiendo

Comment: @user5389726598465 a partir de un determinado nivel los cambios que haces ya no pasan por revisión. Pero que eso no te impida editar, si crees que mi frase en inglés necesita una corrección, adelante. Yo mismo he editado tus preguntas para mejorarlas un poco. Si veo que tu cambio modifica sustancialmente lo que yo quería decir, siempre puedo echar el cambio para atrás y explicarte por qué lo he hecho. Así que si crees que ese "that" sobra, procede con la edición sin miedo.

Comment: Other phrasing would be "but determined", "albeit one determined", "although one determined".

Comment: @Charlie - Ya que quitaste "solo" con la simplificación, creo que no hace falta "except."

Answer (score 2):

Considera estas frases:

> Era música sencilla y bonita.
>
> Era música sencilla pero bonita.
>
> Era música sencilla, pero compuesta por la técnica de los doce tonos, es decir, muy atonal.
>
> Era música sencilla, sólo que compuesta por la técnica de doce tonos, es decir, muy atonal.

Puedo hacer algo parecido en inglés, si hago un ajuste:

> La música era sencilla, pero compuesta etc. | The music was simple, but composed with a twelve tone row, in other words, quite atonal.
>
> La música era sencilla, sólo que compuesta etc. | The music was simple, but composed etc.

Pero en inglés, si usamos "only", entonces ya no podemos suprimir el verbo:

> The music was simple, only that it was composed etc.

Yo lo veo más bien como una limitación del inglés en este caso.